# Zend Framework 2, How do I hydrate when object property and array key don't match?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have the following array:

```
$arr = array(
    'Profile' => 'myClient',
    'Vendor'  => 'myVendor',
);
```

And the following class

```
class MyModel
{
    protected $client;
    protected $vendor;

    getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    setClient($client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    getVendor()
    {
        return $this->vendor;
    }

    setVendor($vendor)
    {
        $this->vendor = $vendor;
    }
}
```

NOTICE that both the array and the class have "vendor" but the array has "profile" while the class has "client".

I'd like to use a hydrator to populate MyModel objects in Zend Framework 2 with the hydrate method (example assumes a hydrator and a MyModel prototype have been injected into my class):

```
$obj = $this->hydrator->hydrate($arr, $this->myModelPrototype)
```

Doing a dump of $obj you would expect to see this:

```
MyModel Object
(
    [client:protected] =>
    [vendor:protected] => myVendor
)
```

However, my desired result would be this:

```
MyModel Object
(
    [client:protected] => myClient
    [vendor:protected] => myVendor
)
```

My Question is, is there any way to customize the hydrator so it will populate the "client" property with the "Profile" value?

At first, I thought I could use a hydrator strategy but that can only alter the values, not the keys. Or, maybe this is some kind of design flaw in my application and there should never be a reason to have to do this?

Thanks for any help / advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you correct, you can solve you're Problem with a NamingStrategy. ZF2 ships some Naming Strategies which are used in several hydrators. unfortunately i did not find any documentation about this. You can find existing Naming Strategies https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stdlib/tree/master/src/Hydrator/NamingStrategy here.

An example how you set your own, custom naming strategy is available here http://blog.igorvorobiov.com/2014/12/29/advanced-hydrator-usage-in-zend-framework-2/ written by Igor Vorobiov.

P.S.: there is documentation for the current naming strategies. I think the MapNamingStrategy fits your needs. See at http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.namingstrategy.mapnamingstrategy.html

HTH